# Making search in cache and in BD after checking changes in variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making search through my DB. For example I have two fields in DB(id & name). User start typing into input "stack". After he stopped typing my angular controller make query to DB, then get a result and display it. After that user again begin typing into input "over". So in input value = "stackover". And after this typing there is no query to DB, search coming through cache. But if user don't type "over", and delete one symbol "k" so the value in input become "stac" then  it is going a query to DB. So, the question is how can I check this out?

```
$scope.value//value of input
if(check()) search_cache()// the question is how to make this check
else $http.post("search.php",$scope.value...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "stackoverflow";
console.log(text.search("stack"));// 0
console.log(text.search("stac"));// -1
```

The search() method searches a string for a specified value, and returns the position of the match.